# Qt Creator crashes when attempting to open .ui forms editor

Tags: qt, user-interface, ubuntu, crash, segmentation-fault

Since a week ago, everytime I try to edit a form .ui in my Qt Creator project, the program crashes and closes. This segmentation fault error details are displayed in the image below:

[image: Error description]

**What I already tried**

1. Even if I try to start over a new project, the problem remains.
2. I tried also to operate Qt Creator with full admin permissions, and
   still it fails.
3. I uninstalled and reinstalled Qt. The same thing happens.

**Conditions**

I run Qt Creator in a Xubuntu OS (version 14.04).
The Qt version is in the image above.

Has this happened already to you? Any idea what this could be? Any troubleshooting suggestions?
Thank you!

Comment: Could be a bug, but if I were you I'd upgrade to the latest version of Qt before filing a bug report.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I managed to find a solution that worked.

1. I opened a terminal and wrote sudo apt-get purge qtcreator* (instead of remove). This way I managed to remove all dependencies.
2. Then I installed Qt directly from the site: http://www.qt.io/download/

This way worked fine.

Comment: Just noticed the same issue.
I can't open a project (dating from 2010) with my Archlinux installed QtCreator (v4.2.0, Qt 5.7.1) but with a version downloaded from Qt (v4.0) I can open the form.
Any ideas as to why that happens ? And more importantly, how to get it working on the latest QtCreator ?